# Determine whether the given relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

**Problems:**

1.) R = {(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)}

2.) R = {(x, y) ¦ y - x is an odd integer}

3.) R = {(x, y) ¦ y - x is a multiple of 3}

**Attempt:**

By definition, a relation is equivalent if it is transitive, reflexive, and symmetrical. If either one of these sets fail any of these tests, then the relation is not an equivalence relation.

1.)

**Checking if it's reflexive.**

(0,0) is present

(0,0) is present

(0,0) is present

(1,1) is present

(1,1) is present

(2,2) is present

Thus this relation is **reflexive**.

**Checking if symmetrical.**

(0,0) is present

(1,0) is not present

Thus this is not **symmetrical** and it is not an **equivalence relation**.

2.)

**Checking if reflexive**

This relation fails because of two axioms:

**1st axiom:** Adding two odd integers will result in an even integer.

**2nd axiom:** Adding two even integers will also result in an even integer.

Not to mention that you are always going to get zero, an even number, when you subtract the same x values every time.

The only time it is ever odd is when you have an odd and an even number.

Thus this relations fails the **reflexive test** and it is not an **equivalence relation.**

3.)

**Checking if reflexive:**

This relation is **reflexive** because of this rule.

An integer a is a multiple of an integer b means that ab=integer.
so, as 0 divided by any integer (except zero itself) yields an integer.

**Checking if symmetrical:**

No this is not symmetrical simply because not every number is a multiple of three.

Here is one case: 9 - 5 = 4 and 5 - 9 = -4. Neither of these are multiples of 3.

Thus this relations fails the **symmetrical test** and it is not an **equivalence relation.**

**Is all of my work correct?**

Comment: For the second relation, there's a much easier way to check for reflexivity: you just need to check if $ (x,x) \in R$ according to the definition, this must be equivalent to $x-x=2k+1 $ which is of course false because...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fine up until the analysis of the last relation.

Recall that $R$ is symmetric iff $(\forall x,y)[(x,y) \in R \Rightarrow (y,x) \in R]$. Now, suppose $(x,y) \in R$. Then $y-x$ is a multiple of $3$. What can you say about $x-y$?

Comment: Before I answer your question, are you saying that the test I did for part 3,    9 - 5 = 4 and 5 - 9 = -4, and concluding that it is not a multiple of 3 is invalid?

Comment: In regards to your question, if  y-x is a multiple of 3 and then of course it's inverse, x-y,  will a multiple of 3 as well.

Comment: Well, you checked if $(5,9) \in R$, and found that it wasn't. So it's irrelevant if $(9,5) \in R$. For $R$ to be symmetric, *if* you have an $(x,y) \in R$, *then* you must also have $(y,x) \in R$. Yes, $x-y$ will also be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: oh I understand. you're applying the conditional statement. Where F implies T is logically equivalent to true. That means every case is symmetrical. Because if 5,9 is not symmetrical, then it is irrelevant but if x-y is true, then it is always true.

Comment: I guess now I have to check if it is transitive.

Comment: Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: While checking if it is transitive, I realized that it doesn't matter if you have three integers that are multiple of three,two or one. It will all evaluate to T and T implies true or F and F implies F or T and F implies F. Thus it is equivalent. Do you agree?

Comment: Er, I'm not sure what you're saying, but consider: suppose $(x,y),(y,z) \in R$. Then $y-x$ and $z-y$ are multiples of $3$. Hence their sum is a multiple of $3$. But their sum is equal to $(z-y) + (y-x)$....

Comment: Well, while going through multiple cases, I noticed sometimes very interesting. Now, I pretty sure if we chose three integers that were multiples of three, this will always be true. But what if x and y were multiples of 3 but z was something like 5 or 7(Not a multiple of 3). Then you would get something like T and F implies F which is F implies F which is true. Somewhat similar if you choose one multiple of 3 and 2 integers that were not a multiple of three. This is what I'm getting at.

Comment: Yes, your observation is correct.

Comment: Thanks. So it would seem that the last problem is an equivalent relation.

Comment: You're right; it is an equivalence relation.